# Некорректно работает AJAX пагинация

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

**Всем привет**
На сайте есть пагинация к статьям, которая работает следующим образом: пользователь нажимает кнопку 'Показать больше статей', после чего добавляется еще N постов. У каждой отдельной статьи  есть кнопка 'Добавить в избранное', которая тоже работает на AJAX. Суть проблемы в том, что когда оба аякса подключены(пагинация и избранное), после нажатии на клавишу пагинации, у всех ново загруженных постов не работает кнопка 'добавить в избранное' и плюс ко всему, эти посты дублируются.
По отдельности оба аякса работают замечательно, как и должны.В чем собственно может быть проблема? Из-за чего все так происходит.

***ajax пагинация:***

```
function ajaxPagination()
{
    $('#pagination a.page-link').each((index, el) =>{
        $(el).click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            let page_url = $(el).attr('href')
            console.log(page_url)

            $.ajax({
                url: page_url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: (data) => {

                    $('.do_it').append( $(data).filter('.do_it').html())

                    $('.pagination').empty()

                    $('.pagination').append( $(data).find('.pagination').html())
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxPagination()
})

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    ajaxPagination()
})
```

***ajax избранное:***

```
const add_to_favorites_url = '/favorites/add/';
const remove_from_favorites_url = '/favorites/remove/';
const favorites_api_url = '/favorites/api/';
const added_to_favorites_class = 'added';


function add_to_favorites(){
    $('.add-to-favorites').each((index, el) => {
        $(el).click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            const type = $(el).data('type');
            const id = $(el).data('id');

            if( $(e.target).hasClass(added_to_favorites_class) ) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: remove_from_favorites_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        type: type,
                        id: id,
                    },
                    success: (data) => {
                        $(el).removeClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                    }
                })
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    url: add_to_favorites_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:{
                        type: type,
                        id: id,
                    },
                    success: (data) => {
                        $(el).addClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                        // get_session_favorites_statistics()
                    }
                })
            };
        })
    })
};


function get_session_favorites() {
    // get_session_favorites_statistics()

    $.getJSON(favorites_api_url, (json) => {
        if (json !== null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $('.add-to-favorites').each((index, el) => {
                    const type = $(el).data('type')
                    const id = $(el).data('id')

                    if ( json[i].type == type && json[i].id == id ){
                        $(el).addClass(added_to_favorites_class)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    add_to_favorites()
    get_session_favorites()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в реализации `add_to_favorites`:

```
$('.add-to-favorites').each((index, el) => {
    $(el).click((e) => {
```

навешивает обработчик событий на каждый элемент отдельно; соответственно, не навешивает на те, которые ещё не подгрузили и на них надо было бы навешивать отдельно. К счастью, есть более грамотный подход, называемый делегированием обработчиков. Суть такая: обработчик навешивается на родителя, который смотрит, кликнули ли в `.add-to-favorites`, и обрабатывает клик так, будто обработчик был привязан непосредственно к `.add-to-favorites`. jQuery умеет такое "из коробки":

```
$('body').on('click', '.add-to-favorites', (e) => {
```

(и дальше тело обработчика). Я тут написал делегирование элементу `body`, в норме, конечно, делегируют контейнеру-потомку, более специфичному задаче – в данном случае тому, в котором находятся все статьи.

Comment: цикл который выгружает все статьи находится в блоке с классом .do_it, я его должен вместо body подставить? я правильно понимаю?

Comment: В консоли отладки пишет: `Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined`, при клике на добавление в избранное

Comment: @Daniil1703 про `.do_it`, видимо, правильно (не видя разметки, не могу сказать уверенно); со второй ошибкой, как я понимаю, разобрались?

Comment: Все работает с вашим кодом, только проблема все также осталась, посты дублируются после подгрузки новых и новые не добавляются

Comment: @Daniil1703 а, ну так вы же, насколько я вижу из кода, делаете запрос всё время по одному урлу (`page_url`), обычно сервер отдаёт новые посты, если в `query`-части урла добавляется что-нибудь типа `page=2` (конкретное query зависит от сервера), а так вам сервер отдаёт все время первые посты (проверьте через dev tools, скорее всего ответ сервера сейчас не меняется)

Comment: С каждым кликом на на пагинацию, сервер возвращает мне новые урлы `?page=2` `?page=3` и тд. Так что все меняется(

Comment: @Daniil1703 возможно, есть смысл задать отдельный вопрос, тут нужно не одно уточнение (вообще, хороший тон в SO – по одной проблеме на вопрос). В частности, верно ли я понял, что `console.log(page_url)` показывает урлы с query, как вы указали выше? (или это только часть?) Что приходит в качестве тела ответа? (далее в зависимости от ответов надо смотреть, какие query действительно поддерживаются сервером либо проверять клиентскую логику)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за информацию, задам новый вопрос, только уже с вашим кодом. Но сначала еще поковыряю код, вдруг что-то получится сделать

Comment: @Daniil1703 ну собственно код, навешивающий обработчик для "избранного", в новом вопросе не понадобится, тут дело только в догрузке пагинации